# What is [ ] in google chrome developer console?

Tags: jquery-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

While testing code in the google chrome developer console, i get 
[]
and sometimes i get "".
The later shows up,when i think there not such strings available with the current selector combinations.But i still couldn't figure out the meaning of the former [] square brakets.
Please help.

Comment: I have have no idea what you are talking about. Where do you get `[]` or `""`? By doing what? Please provide an example or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[] are returned whenever you jquery returns empty object. i.e. you selector expression cant locate what you are trying to search.

whereas "" is just simple string 
i looked into your given site..
when i tried :
$('.four columns alpha') i get object[] (which means there jquery is returning empty object)
but when you write correct expression like :
$('.four.columns') you will get array of Div's which can be used like object.

Hope i'm able to make you understand. if any doubts do write.

And $('.four columns alpha') this is not the right way to select div's with  more than one css class right way is to do something like below:

$('.four.columns.alpha')

Comment: -1 The answer to the question has nothing to do with jQuery. You describe just one of the cases. The answer is pretty simple and the answer of David covers it fine.

Answer (score 2):

With the information that you've given, all we can do is make assumptions. However, when you're logging things to the console, `[]` is an empty array, whereas `""` is an empty string.

Comment: @Felix Kling                                                         in this site www.way2franchise.com , in console type :                          $('.four columns alpha'); and $('.title div>p').text();                         you'll see the square brackets popping.